# Is there a better way of writing the following SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a more concise way to write the following code in MySQL and not just by using a loop in a programming language? table_vw has many many rows and several columns and the sth column has value between 0 and 7

table_vw

```
sth sth_else sth_else ...
7      
.
.
6
.
.
5
.
.
4
.
.
3
.
.
2
.
.
1
.
.
0
.
.


(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 7
LIMIT 12
)
UNION
(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 6
LIMIT 12
)
UNION
(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 5
LIMIT 12
)
UNION
(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 4
LIMIT 12
)
UNION
(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 3
LIMIT 12
)
UNION
(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 2
LIMIT 12
)
UNION
(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 1
LIMIT 12
)
UNION
(
SELECT *
FROM table_vw
WHERE sth = 0
LIMIT 12
)
```

Comment: `limit` without `order by`? what are you doing?

Comment: why should i use order_by? the table_vw is already in order suppose there are 100 of each sth i want only 12 of each one

Comment: there's no such thing as "already in order", that's just luck. you shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: @pouya there is no such thing as 'the table_vw is already in order'. You should always use `ORDER BY` if you expect ordered results. If you want 12 of each the method you are using is the best one i can think of if there is an index on `(sth,<whatever column you use in order by>)`.

Comment: The table view is view a which is ordered by sth that's why i said the table is already in order anyway i don't know what's the role of order by in this situation

Comment: so u guys say the way i'm doing this is the only way of doing this?

Comment: If `table_vw` is a view this may not be the best way of doing it (I am not familiar with the way MySQL uses indexes with views so i can't tell). You should run explain on one of those SELECT's and if it has a type = 'ref' it will probably be OK to use UNION with all the values.

Comment: @Vatev thanks maybe i should redesign my view. if the table_view is a table (not a view) which is orderd by sth is this the only way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then you are very close.

All you need is

```
Select * 
From table_vw
Where sth <= 7 AND sth >= 0
Limit 12;
```

The where statement incorporates all the unions you have made.

If you're trying to get a limited 12 results per sth column, then what you have may be the only way to accomplish the feat.

Comment: Just like @Sebas-es answer this will not give the same result.

Comment: hence my comment at the bottom of my answer.... I thought perhaps pouya was overcomplicating his question

Comment: Yes, that is likely, but since the other answer got downvoted because of it I thought it should be clear that this one is the same. Also I think the comment at the bottom didn't exist at that point :)

Comment: definitely did... notice that my answer does not have an "edited" annotation. but that's ok

Comment: It's possible that i missed it but i cant tell if it was edited because it only gets "edited" if you edit after a certain time. You get "free" edits for the first few minutes.

Comment: @GK1667 this will give only 12 rows where sth is between 0 and 7 clearly not the same result

Comment: everyone should try reading this bottom line..... reread my answer @pouya, notice the bottom line

Comment: When your whole answer is misleading is quite strange to refer to the last line...